# Mule flow not getting triggered from other flow through VM endpoints

Tags: mule, esb

I am having two mule flows.
VM is outbound for one and inbound for one.
When the first flow sends the message to VM outbound, this process is not triggering the second flow in which VM is inbound.on

Exception Message :

```html
org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException: Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=vm://messaging-path?connector=.vm.connector, connector=VMConnector
{
  name=vm.connector
  lifecycle=start
  this=4d4b2560
  numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers=4
  createMultipleTransactedReceivers=true
  connected=true
  supportedProtocols=[vm]
  serviceOverrides=<none>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally these kind of issues occur when the second mule flow's initial State is defined as Stopped. 
Please remove this attribute and see.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure followings:
1. Queue name should be same at both endpoints.
2. Try with Action as None.
3. Make sure exchange pattern for both are set as one-way.